# simultaneously api request take higher time in seprate vue.js app with laravel backend

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

- "laravel": "9.x",
- "vue": "2.x",
- "axios": "^0.27.2"

I am using **separate** vue.js applications and **laravel 9.x**, multiple API requests take too much time I don't know why it happens,

- case 1:

a get user API call takes 500ms, if I call this API 10 times at the same time response time of each request will be 7s in the browser network tab. whereas a single API call works fine

[image]

- case 2:

if multiple API requests call the same time it's taking too much time like 7s but if I call each API individually each API take max 500ms, inside postman as well as inside the application network window of the browser

[image]

**endpoint**

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/services?type=client`

`Route::resource('services', ServiceController::class);`

**code for get services inside the controller**

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $services = Service::when($request->q, function ($query, $q) {
            return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$q}%");
        })
            ->when($request->type, function ($query, $type) {
                return $query->where('type', '=', $type);
            })
            ->when($request->sortBy, function ($query, $sortBy) {
                return $query->orderBy($sortBy, request('sortDesc') == 'true' ? 'asc' : 'desc');
            })
            ->when($request->page, function ($query, $page) {
                return $query->offset($page - 1);
            })
            ->paginate($request->perPage);
      
        return $this->respond([
            'status' => true,
            'message' => 'Services has been Fetched Successfully!',
            'data' => [
                'services' => ServiceResource::collection($services)
            ],
        ]);
    }
```

**resource class ServiceResource.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ServiceResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'uuid' => $this->resource->service_uuid,
            'name' => $this->resource->name,
            'type' => $this->resource->type,
            'icon' => $this->resource->icon,
            'image' => $this->resource->image,
            'is_selected' => false,
        ];
    }
}
```

**API call from postman**
[image]

query execution time is 29ms sec for a single API
[image]

if I call API at once from the front-end vue.js app then the response time is normal(500ms ),

[image]

**request payload**
[image]

**request preview**
[image]

but if I call this API multiple times at once(simultaneously) then its response increases(5 to 7 sec),
[image]

**in case of multiple API call simultaneously, why does it take (5 to 7) sec or it's an issue related to the front-end app that the question?**

Comment: What is your question exactly ? is it "why when i overload the server, the performance drops?" if so, yes the performance drops if overloaded. especially if the code behind the end point is bad (500ms is a loooot).

Comment: 500ms seems quite big already tbh. Why is it so slow to send an answer?

Comment: yeah 500ms very bad response time, I move my code to production it's working fine, and this response time reduces by nearly about 300ms,

the question is, there are 10 API call, if call them individually each API take max 500ms, but  if call all of them are at the same time then the response time of the API become 7s,  @N69S

Comment: @kissu on my local environment, with wamp server it takes 500ms but on a live environment on AWS it's pretty much fine

Comment: guys, it's not about bad code, I check my code and query response time, I check the response time with a laravel package **telescope** it takes 29ms in query execution and the code contains only one resource class for API, and the response object with min database attribute, @kissu

Comment: what answer are you expecting for your question? we dont know how your server is running, you didn't provide any "control" request with timing (so you/we dont know where the issue is (installation or code)) we can only say, yeah it's slow. **Add more details to your question** if you want any useful answer from anyone.